# How to achieve thread safety for applications deployed in Kubernetes clusters?

Tags: mysql, mongodb, multithreading, kubernetes, statefulset

My databases (`mongodb` and `mysql`) are declared as `StatefulSet` in `yaml` files. Backend framework is `django`. If I define functions that perform write operations (edit or delete) as `async`, it gonna be thread safe, right? Should I use locks or mutexes?

Comment: What does thread safety have to do with kubernetes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same way you would do it anywhere else. MySQL offers many flavors and modes of transactional safety, which you use depends on your data structures and needs. Mongo is a little less complex but offers plenty of at least hypothetically transactional options.